# cannot open file 'test.csv': No such file or directory Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

Tags: r, directory

I'm having issues reading the data on the desktop version of Rstudio on mac. When I do the usual read.csv it shows the error shown in the title. This is the first time this has happened. I have tried to change my working directory in 'Sessions' at the top and also to read the file with its granularity

[image]

[image: This is my console]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't show error messages or code as images, but put it into you question as text and provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), thanks! You have a space at the end of your path, maybe this is the problem? In general, I would avoid spaces in path names

Comment: The folder name includes a space at the end `Titanic Kaggle `. Try updating your read.csv line to include that space. Additionally, when the working directory is set you can specify a 'relative' path. This means that you should be able to just run `read.csv("test.csv")` after setting your working directory successfully.

Comment: Keep your csv file in the same directory as your markdown document. So you can directly do `Test = read.csv("test.csv")`

Answer (score 0):

You could try `rstudioapi` library to set an unique wd for your script path and then use `read.csv()` where `path= "test.csv"`

```
library(rstudioapi)
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))

Test <- read.csv("test.csv")
```